# Jquery adding items to Object failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var selectedCountries = {};

var id = 1;
var profile = {};

$(".countriesSelection").find('span').each(function() {
  var countryName = $(this).text();
  var profile1 = {};
  profile1.id = id;
  profile1.countryName = countryName;

  $.extend(profile, profile1);
});

$.extend(selectedCountries, profile);

console.log(selectedCountries);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countriesSelection">
  <span>India</span>
  <span>USA</span>
  <span>China</span>
  <span>Japan</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to loop through spans in a div and add the values of spans to a object with one id. I am trying the below, but it adds only one item, how can I add every country and id to object?

[my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xh8L2594/9/)

Comment: You need to store it in array using array.push() instead of $.extend. using extend replacing property of old object. That's why you getting last value only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `array` instead of `object` for variable `selectedCountries`

Run the following snippet

```js
var selectedCountries = [];

var id = 1;

$(".countriesSelection").find('span').each(function() {
  var countryName = $(this).text();
  var profile1 = {};
  profile1.id = id;
  profile1.countryName = countryName;

  selectedCountries.push(profile1)
});

console.log(selectedCountries);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countriesSelection">
  <span>India</span>
  <span>USA</span>
  <span>China</span>
  <span>Japan</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store it in array using array.push() instead of $.extend. Using extend replacing property of old object. That's why you getting last value only.

Try this:

```js
 

var id = 1;
var profile = [];

$(".countriesSelection").find('span').each(function() {
  var countryName = $(this).text();
  var profile1 = {};
  profile1.id = id;
  profile1.countryName = countryName;

  profile.push(profile1);
});



console.log(profile);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countriesSelection">
  <span>India</span>
  <span>USA</span>
  <span>China</span>
  <span>Japan</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With `$.extend`, you're overwriting any previous properties assigned. If the first iteration turns `profile` into `{ id: 1, countryName: 'India' }`, the second iteration will overwrite those properties to `{ id: 2, countryName: 'USA' }`.

You should probably use an array instead of an object, and then push to the array - and avoid jQuery entirely, there's no need for it.

```js
const selectedCountries = [...document.querySelectorAll('.countriesSelection > span')]
  .map((span, i) => ({ id: i + 1, countryName: span.textContent }));
console.log(selectedCountries);
```

```html
<div class="countriesSelection">

<span>India</span>
<span>USA</span>
<span>China</span>
<span>Japan</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 
An `array` of `objects` for this. Simply use this code.

https://jsfiddle.net/xh8L2594/21/

```
var selectedCountries = []
var id = 1;
$(".countriesSelection").find('span').each(function() {
  var countryName = $(this).text();
  selectedCountries.push({
  id:id, // update id accordingly
  country:countryName
  }) 
});

console.log(selectedCountries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method to return an `array` to get the required result with combinations of **ES6**.

> The [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

**DEMO**

```js
const id = 1;

let profile = $.map($(".countriesSelection span"), item => {
  return {id,countryName:$(item).text()};
})

console.log(profile);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countriesSelection">
  <span>India</span>
  <span>USA</span>
  <span>China</span>
  <span>Japan</span>
</div>
```